# BluetoothChat sample from android SDK - why app never is killed during the onPause method

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I was testing BluetoothChat sample from android SDK. BluetoothChat never is killed during the onPause method. Just in case the user sends that order by back button. In general apps are killed due to inactivity timer (onPause method) - another app with highest priority requiring memory. how is it possible in Bluetoothchat?

[image]

Comment: I donot understande your question. Are you asking "how to test that  `BluetoothChat` is killed because some other app requires memory"? Note that an activity is killed in OnDestroy not in OnPause.

Comment: Take a look the flowchart above. According the picture, the activity is killed either in OnPause or OnStop. When in OnDestroy the activity is shutting down. I am looking for a way to avoid the kill of activity from OnPause. I realized that BluetoothChat sample from android SDK doesn´t happen that. But I don't know how..